# php update database when list is created

Tags: php

I'm new in php and I learn a lot from stackowerflow.
I'm working on some kind of warehouse script. Most of it is done but I have problems with quantity. When I create receipt or delivery note everything work fine but when I try to change quantity at this documents then I lost myself.
it work like this when I create delivery note:

1. search for buyer
2. add the buyer
3. search article
4. add the article (manualy specify quantity), automaticaly update quantity at my lager (if I had 5 pcs and add 3 pcs my lager is 2 pcs)

in case I make a mistake and I wanna change quantity I add one button called EDIT so I can change it. Then troubles begin. I can change it at delivery note but I cant recover my lager.
Because I'm totaly new I'm using the simpliest add, update and delete query.
So I'm wonder Can I somehow update my lager after I finish my delivery note.
Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: We need to see the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Part of your code will be very helpful to help you solve your issue. Would you please update your question with parts of your code?